# Can't set Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, datetime

I have a date like this: `20-03-2016 10:28:24.8402750`
the field on my database is a `DateTime`. When I try to insert a record with the date above, I get: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

I also tried with `TimeStamp` and same problem. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

this is my code for generate the date:

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
$now->getTimezone();
$result = $now->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);
return $result;
```

Comment: Post exactly what have you tried.

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen Check my update...

Comment: Why you are doing this `. substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8)`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 only for get micro time.. but I don't need more this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the format string `d-m-Y H:i:s` to `Y-m-d H:i:s`, after you code looks like:

```
$result = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And also remove milliseconds not required;

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime` value in the default format:

```
2016-03-20 10:28:24
```

Answer (score 0):

After selecting TimeStamp , use default for current time stamp. It will work then